# Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionOverflowButtonStyle'. Error:(27, -1)

Tags: android-appcompat

I am running a project on intellij. I am facing a problem. I used appcompat v7 library.SDK is 5.1, API level 22. Adding appcompat v7 and v4 jar as dependency. when I compile my code ,it showing following errors..... when I click any parent item in appcompat `style.xml`, it navigates to the source correctly, but when I compile my code, it showing error no resource found...

```
Information:10/07/15 10:32 AM - Compilation completed with 36 errors and 0 warnings in 30s 150ms
/Users/anujaggarwal/Android_Software/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/styles_base.xml
Error:(37, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] /Users/anujaggarwal/Android_Software/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/styles_base.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionOverflowButtonStyle'.
Error:(27, -1) android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] /Users/anujaggarwal/Android_Software/android-sdk-macosx/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/styles_base.xml:27:....
```

following are the dependencies of my project... 
appcompat library..
support v7 appcompat.jar..
android support v4.jar..

Comment: Are you compiling with api21?

Comment: yes,i tried with api 21 also,but same error showing

Comment: i compiled with both api 22 and 21